# Why is my hardware RAID volume not mounting on boot in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, raid, mount, external-hard-drive

I just installed windows 7 ultimate 32bit on my machine.

I configured the NVIDIA RAID utility on boot to have 2 external 1TB drives drives in RAID0.

I have another 80GB HDD I use as my OS drive.

The system boots fine, but the 2TB RAID volume is not mounted.  I go into disk management and mount it without a problem to D:.

However when I reboot, the 2TB RAID volume is again not mounted.

How can I make sure the 2TB RAID volume is mounted every time I boot?

Comment: looks like a question for superuser.com to me

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the DiskPart utility and set the Automount option for it:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(WS.10).aspx